# What is a good use case to implement for learning Functional Programming?

Tags: functional-programming, jvm-languages

I am a Java programmer looking to learn Functional Programming.  My aim is to implement a simple use case (say a simple text-based game like tic-tac-toe) in various Functional Programming languages (i.e. Clojure, Scala) in order to learn the ins and outs of each.

Are there any FP gurus out there who can recommend a specific use case that I could begin with?  Or is Tic Tac Toe (noughts and crosses) good enough to get started?

Note that at this point I will be focusing on JVM based languages.

Comment: I hate to say it, but this is too broad and/or primarily opinion based. In addition, whether you use a JVM language or not doesn't matter, does it?

Comment: I added the note about JVM in case it was relevant for someone, but I see your point.

Comment: Take a look at: https://www.coursera.org/course/progfun - it covers the basics of functional programming using Scala. It should be easier to learn other FP languages.

Comment: You can also look at implementing some of, say, list operations, in the preferred language of your choice just using the primitive operations. For example how would you implement a 'set' by using a list and the operations available for working on list. If you are into Clojure, try http://www.4clojure.com/

Comment: @AkosKrivachy I think the first part of https://www.coursera.org/course/proglang is a lot focussed towards fundamentals of functional programming, without the noise of Scala syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Tic-Tac-Toe would help you, indeed. Let me share how I started, I started learning by,

- Writing arithmetic functions in Clojure; for example, next-prime, prime?, factors, prime-factors, and stuff like that
- Then making those idiomatic as far as I could
- Then ask question here, or anywhere, to improve a particular function

Here is the link of [math.arithmetic](https://github.com/totient/math.arithmetic).

Note: It's missing a decent README. I'll put that later. Actually, I never thought of sharing this because it's so trivial.

**[Edited]**

You can try [4clojure](http://www.4clojure.com/).

> 4Clojure is a resource to help fledgling clojurians learn the language through interactive problems.

**[Edited, again]**

There is also [Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net/), which many people have found useful for precisely this sort of thing.

> Project Euler is a series of challenging mathematical/computer programming problems that will require more than just mathematical insights to solve.

Comment: Tic-Tac-Toe make a nice small problem domain that is well understood.  Any small problem domain that you understand and are interested in would make project for learning a new language.  You want to do something you know well so you can focus on the implementation rather than the problem being solved.

Comment: @dsm: A very appropriate addition, indeed. Thanks.